# No encuentro como trabajar con Shinobi 5.0 en Laravel 6.x sin ShinobiTrait

Tags: laravel, permisos

estoy intentando introducirme Laravel y ya está la versión 6, y fue la que instalé. Buscando la forma de manejar roles y permisos me encuentro con muy buenos tutoriales pero todo sobre la Versión 5 de Laravel y con versiones de Shinobi 3.x. Cuando mando instalar el paquete me instala la version 5.0 de Shinobi pero ya esta no cuenta con el ShinobiTrait que me permitía usar la etiqueta @can, la cual establecidos los permisos y luego de configurar mi modelo Users, entendía y daba acceso a estos

```
@can('notificacion.index')
    <li class="navbar-item">  
        <a href="{{ route('notificacion.index') }}">Notificaciones</a>
    </li>
@endcan
```

Comment: En youtube hay un tutorial bien explicado sobre roles y permisos:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhCiuvlix-rSgQNLIl7Qg2KbQni3fz-ea

Answer (score 0):

Prueba importando Concerns

`use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasRolesAndPermissions;`

en kernel si lo usas asi

`'permission'=>\Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasRole::class,`

https://caffeinatedpackages.com/guide/packages/shinobi.html#usage

Creo q el nuevo problema es en el registro de permission en el kernel.

'permission'        =>  \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasPermission::class,

Para la validacion de permisos en rutas en la nueva version de shinobi no existe el archivo UserHasPermission... el modo rapido que encontre de solucionarlo es crear el archivo UserHasPermission.php en la carpeta \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\

```
<?php

namespace Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware;

use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Models\Role;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class UserHasPermission
{
/**
* @var Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
*/
protected $auth;

/**
 * Create a new UserHasPermission instance.
 *
 * @param Guard $auth
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Run the request filter.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Closure                 $closure
 * @param array|string             $permissions
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permissions)
{
    if ($this->auth->check()) {
        if (!$this->auth->user()->can($permissions)) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 403);
            }

            abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }
    } else {
        $guest = Role::whereSlug('guest')->first();

        if ($guest) {
            if (!$guest->can($permissions)) {
                if ($request->ajax()) {
                    return response('Unauthorized.', 403);
                }

                abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo por responderme, esta parte ya la vi, donde tengo el problema es cuando trato de ponerle en el modelo User la clase: Caffeinated\Shinobi\Traits\ShinobiTrait; que aparece en https://caffeinatedpackages.com/guide/packages/shinobi.html#_3-4 . Ya en la version 5 de Shinobi, esta clase no aparece y aunque si sale bien las validaciones con las etiquetas @can, cuando acceso al route no me da permiso

Comment: Por lo que veo la pregunta es otra entonces... Formulabas que no te permitia usar @scan. Traits cambio por Concerns y Use ShinobiTrait por Use HasRolesAndPermissions...  Dejame testear a ver como me va y te aviso...   (https://caffeinatedpackages.com/guide/packages/shinobi.html#usage)

Comment: Si al principio fue eso y llegué al punto que me sugeristes luego. Gracias amigo

Comment: Para la validacion de permisos en rutas en la nueva version de shinobi no existe el archivo UserHasPermission... el modo rapido que encontre de solucionarlo es crear el archivo UserHasPermission.php en la carpeta \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\

Answer (score 0):

En la versión 5.0 ya no se hace el uso de ShinobiTrait, solamente debes colocar en el modelo User lo siguiente: **use Caffeinated\Shinobi\Concerns\HasRolesAndPermissions**, luego en la clase colocar use Notifiable, **HasRolesAndPermissions**

Comment: Veo que hablan de shinobi 5.0 pero en la documentacion solo me sale shinobi 4.0

Answer (score 0):

la versión 5 de Shinobi no trae este midleware

```
'permission' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasPermission::class,
```

Lo debes crear manualmente.

1. Crea el middleware

   `php artisan make:middleware CheckPermission`
2. Ve al archivo que se ha creado app/Http/Middleware/CheckPermission.php y reemplaza el método handle(..)

   ```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permissions)
   {
       if (!auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo($permissions)) {
           return response()->json(["res" => false, "message" => "No tienes autorización para ingresar"], 403);
       }
       return $next($request);
   }
   ```
3. En el archivo app/Http/Kernel

   ```
       protected $routeMiddleware = [
           'has.role' => \Caffeinated\Shinobi\Middleware\UserHasRole::class,
           'permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
       ];
   ```
4. Y ya puedes usar el middleware en la rutas

```
    Route::get('funcionarios', 'FuncionarioController@index')->name('funcionarios.index')->middleware('permission:funcionarios.index');
```

Saludos, espero que te sirva.